# What is the range of BERT CLS values?

Tags: nlp, classification, bert-language-model, transformer-model

As you can see in my title, I am interested in the value range of BERT.
I read through the BERT paper but it is all still a little confusing for me. At the end of a Classification, BERT has the calculated CLS Token (Classification Token) which is a 768 long float array.

But what are the maximum/minimum possible values in that array?

Answer (score 1):

My read is that when the developers want the encoder to produce a sequence of hidden states for sentence classification, they chose to use the CLS token to reduce this sequence to a single vector.

There are many ways of representing a sentence vector (e.g., attention, min/max pooling). In BERT iirc they just take the hidden state of the first token in the vector. So the CLS token is just added to the start of each sentence.

From what I can tell the overall shape of the layer is similar to this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I understood that. But the question is, what's in the CLS output vector. The CLS is a vector with a default length of 768 (for standard BERT) and has float values around zero in it. What would be the maximum / minimum float value?

Comment: TBH I am not sure re the min/max float value. I do however know you can check your special tokens via:  

`tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')  
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')  
clsToken = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids('[CLS]'  
print(clsToken)  
print(tokenizer.all_special_tokens)`  

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961194/how-does-bertforsequenceclassification-classify-on-the-cls-vector