# Is BertForSequenceClassification using the CLS vector?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

In the hugging face [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/536ea2aca234fb48c5c69769431d643b0d93b233/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1552), `pooled_output = outputs[1]` is used.

```py
        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
        )

        pooled_output = outputs[1]
```

Shouldn't it be `pooled_output = outputs[0]`? (This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883003/20898396) mentioning BertPooler seems to be outdated)

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62981360/20898396) answer, it seems that the CLS token learns a sentence level representation. I am confused as to why/how masked language modelling would lead to the start token learning a sentence level representation. (I am thinking that `BertForSequenceClassification` freezes the Bert model and only trains the classification head, but maybe that's not the case)

Would a sentence embedding be equivalent or even better than the [CLS] token embedding?